# Plot hlines on fixed x values when click happens between x values

Tags: python, events, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

On this piece of code below I'm simulating a problem that I'm currently dealing with and I've been trying to figure it out for quite some time now (I'm practicing matplotlib by the way).

What it's supposed to do is: when I click somewhere on the plot a little horizontal red line should be created on the nearest vertical line, which means that the horizontal line is supposed to be plotted only on fixed x values (in this case the x values are the x values of the vertical lines). The y value is irrelevant because I want the horizontal line to be plotted on any y value.

In other words: the vertical lines should be like magnets for the horizontal lines. The vertical line that is the closest to the click should pull the horizontal line.

I belive that the event.xdata is the key here, but I couldn't find a solution for it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(24):
    plt.axvline(i/50)
plt.xlim(0,1)
plt.ylim(0,1)

def pick(event):
    if event.xdata # ???
        plt.ion()
        plt.hlines(event.ydata,event.xdata-0.01,event.xdata+0.01,colors='r',linestyle='solid')
    else:
        pass

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',pick)
plt.show()
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare `event.xdata` to your "magnet" x values inside of the `pick` function, which you aren't doing at all right now.

You can get the nearest value from a list of given values like this:

```
nearestMagnetValue = min(magnetValues, key=lambda x: abs(event.xdata - x))
```

So putting that in your code, something like this would work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()

magnetValues = [i/50 for i in range(24)]
for i in magnetValues:
    plt.axvline(i)

plt.xlim(0,1)
plt.ylim(0,1)

def pick(event):
    if event.xdata: # ???
        nearestMagnetValue = min(magnetValues, key=lambda x: abs(event.xdata - x))
        plt.ion()
        plt.hlines(event.ydata,nearestMagnetValue-0.01,nearestMagnetValue+0.01,colors='r',linestyle='solid')
    else:
        pass

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',pick)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If you don't mind, could you please explain me  min(magnetValues, key=lambda x: abs(event.xdata - x)) ? I'm rather new in python.

Comment: Hm, it's hard to know how much to explain without knowing what you're familiar with. [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) takes a Python [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) as an argument and returns the smallest element of the list. In your case, however, you don't want the smallest element of the list, you want the element with the smallest distance from `event.xdata`. Fortunately, `min` also allows you to supply a `key` argument, which is the metric it will use to define what "smallest" means.

Comment: In this example, we provide as a key a `lambda` expression, which is just a way of defining a function inline without giving it a name. Instead we could have defined this smallest distance function using a `def`, which you may be more used to, and then just using `key=functionName` where `functionName` is the name for the function you write. There is a very good Python tutorial at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/, which would give you a very good foundation if you are able to work through it. Best of luck, and enjoy Python!